# How to call a function from other independent component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-context

I am trying to call a function (component A) from different component (component K).
Both component does not have any relationship between them.

below is some example code for my problem-

**Component A**

```
const ComponentA= () => {
const start =()=>{
        console.log('function called')
                  }
return ()
}
```

**Component K**

```
const ComponentK= () => {
              

    return (
           <img className='tour' src={tourIcon}  height={25} width={25} onClick={start} />
           )
    }
```

here in above example- i want to call a function of component A from component K **(both are independent compoent-does not have any relationship)** on onClick.

please help

Comment: They're not independent if K is entangled with A this way.

Answer (score 3):

Use react context. Define function in context. Use it wherever you want

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html